# Date is not stored correctly in a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I stored this date in a cookie:

```
Tue Jun 26 2012 15:38:41 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

and now I need to print it in this form:

```
06/26/2012 15:38
```

So I write this code:

```
echo $_COOKIE['date'];
echo date('m/d/Y g:i A', strtotime($_COOKIE['date']));
```

but I get this:

```
Tue Jun 26 2012 15:38:41 GMT 0200 (CEST)
12/31/1969 7:00 PM
```

instead of:

```
 06/26/2012 15:38
```

Why?

Comment: There is no plus between `GMT` and `0200` in your output, maybe you have missed something?

Answer (score 2):

strtotime does not seem to understand the date format, you can try to parse it with DateTime::createFromFormat or you can try to store it in another format

Comment: Is there any approve link? Can't find `strtotime` supported formats list

Comment: yes there is : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php (didn't check if your format is supported)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its easier to store the timestamp in the cookie and not the date string.

```
$_COOKIE['date'] = time();
```

and then read it direct to the date function.

i have tried this:

```
<?php
setcookie('date', time());
var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo date('m/d/Y g:i A', $_COOKIE['date']);
?>
```

and the result is: **06/25/2012 6:13 PM**

Comment: I stored the datetime but now I get the same problem :(

Comment: @xRobot: I have edited my post. I've tried it and its working. Perhaps there are some other wrong settings.

Answer (score 0):

Because `strtotime` is not recognizing the date format you are using.